# R: Multipling df/matrix with 0s and NAs resulting in differiantiated results

Tags: r

I want to multiply a df with a matrix. The df has 0 values and the matrix has NA values (that is important). By multipling a 0 (in df) with a value (in mat) I get 0 and by multiplying a value (in df) with NA (in mat) I get NA, what is true and totally fine for me. However, when I multiply 0 (df) with NA (mat) I get NA, what is probably true. But is there a way to get 0? As I am interested in those 0s. Here some example data:

```
df0 <- data.frame(a=1, b=0, c=2, d=5, e=0)
mat0 <- matrix(c(NA,2,NA,4,NA),nrow=1, ncol=5)
df_mat0 <- df0 * mat0
```

My expected result (0 in e):

```
   a b  c  d  e
1 NA 0 NA 20  0
```

Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would *not* directly overwrite the values in `mat0` with `0`, but rather create a temporary object, or, even easier, use the following line of code

```
df0*`[<-`(mat0,df0==0,0)
#   a b  c  d e
#1 NA 0 NA 20 0
```

The function

```
`[<-`(a,b,c)
```

returns `a[b]=c` but actually does not change `a` itself.

Edit: As per request of the OP (see comment below), here some more code.

I assume `A[[y]]` and `x` correspond to `df0` and `mat0`, respectively. If so, try

```
Map(function(x,y) A[[y]]*`[<-`(x,A[[y]]==0,0),B,sub('\\..*','',names(B)))
```

Comment: I really like your answer. However, I am trying to implement your answer on lists (see my former <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33800893/r-how-to-run-a-function-calculation-on-two-lists-based-on-their-names">question</a>). So I tryied to implement your answer on this answer using Map (assuming example data A shows NA instead of 0): `Map(function(x,y) A[[y]]*`[<-`(x,y==0, 0), B, gsub('\\..*','',names(B)))`. However I didn't get it to run, do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to replace those NA's in `mat0` by 0 that are multiplied by 0 in `df0`. I am not sure how general this solution would be though (i.e. would it work with your actual dataset?):

```
mat0[df0 == 0][is.na(mat0[df0 == 0])] <- 0
df0 * mat0
```

Result:

```
   a b  c  d e
1 NA 0 NA 20 0
```

Comment: Nice. Do you an idea how to lapply this on lists? As both are lists

Comment: Something like `mapply(function(x,y) {x[y == 0][is.na(x[y == 0])]}, x = mat, y = df)` could work. Edit an extension to your question and I will try to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an alternative:

Seems like an `ifelse` would suffice for this:

```
unlist(ifelse(df0 == 0L, 0, mat0 * df0))
[1] NA  0 NA 20  0
```

In which case it deals with the `0` cases.