# R: Multipling matrices with 0s and NAs resulting in differiantiated results on LISTS

Tags: r, list

I want to multiply matrices, one containing values and 0s, the other one contains instead of 0s NAs (which is important). This is a new question on two older questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33800893/r-how-to-run-a-function-calculation-on-two-lists-based-on-their-names) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34087072/r-multipling-df-matrix-with-0s-and-nas-resulting-in-differiantiated-results)), as I have not been able to combine both answers into a final solution. Here some sample data:

```
A <- list("111"= matrix(c(NA,NA,100,200,NA,NA),
                             nrow = 1, byrow = T),
          "112"= matrix(c(10,90,NA,30,10,90),
                             nrow = 1, byrow = T))
B <- list("111.2012"=matrix(c(1, 0, 6, 0, 1, 0),
                             nrow = 1, byrow = T),
           "112.2012"=matrix(c(6, 2, 2, 0, 3, 1),
                             nrow = 1, byrow = T),
           "111.2011"=matrix(c(3, 2, 0, 0, 1, 9),
                             nrow = 1, byrow = T),
           "112.2011"=matrix(c(1, 2, 0, 0, 7, 0),
                             nrow = 1, byrow = T))
```

First is important to match the lists by names (or in case of B the first part of the name), for this I use the answer of question (1):

```
 Map(function(x,y) A[[y]]*x, B, gsub('\\..*','',names(B)))
```

By multipling a 0 (in B) with a value (in A) I get 0 and by multiplying a value (in B) with NA (in A) I get NA, what is true and totally fine for me. However, when I multiply 0 (B) with NA (A) I get NA, what is probably true. But is there a way to get 0 (this was my question 2 however not including 1)?

For this I get among others the answer (question 2):

```
B*`[<-`(A,B==0,0)
```

and a possible result for lists, with my old code (1):

```
Map(function(x,y) A[[y]]*`[<-`(x,A[[y]]==0,0),B,sub('\\..*','',names(B)))
```

which I realized that A and B should be turned. However, I am trying since hours to fix this problem. Do you have ideas how the code should look like (also possible with another answer of 2 or even anew one)? Thanks.

My expected result is:

```
> res
$`111.2012`
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]   NA    0  600    0   NA    0

$`112.2012`
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]   60  180   NA    0   30   90

$`111.2011`
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]   NA   NA    0    0   NA   NA

$`112.2011`
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]   10  180    0    0   70    0
```

Note: that in element one ($'111.2012') the 2nd and 6th entries are 0s as in element four ($'112.2011') 3rd entry.

Comment: Just add a `replace`, i.e. `Map(function(x,y) replace(A[[y]], x==0, 0) *x , B, gsub('\\..*','',names(B)))`